# how to implement cloudinary Product Gallery in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cloudinary

I am trying to use Cloudinary Product Gallery in my eCommerce project, but no idea how to implement it.

this Cloudinary Product Gallery: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/product_gallery

I want to implement it in this component.

```
    class FullProduct extends Component {
      render() {
       return <div id="my-gallery"></div>;
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you need to make a third-party lib control an element inside React. Is that right?

Comment: @AlysonMaia not exactly, Cloudinary Product Gallery is just a widget for displaying a collection of images, and I wanna use that widget in my component but I don't know how that works with React.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding script import in your public/index.html file as @alyson Maya mentioned.
you can access your resources through Window object, and this works just fine.

```
    class FullProduct extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
      const myWidget = window.cloudinary.galleryWidget({
      cloudName: "cloudName",
      container: "#my-gallery",
      mediaAssets: [
        {
          publicId: "products/excmml5kpl",
          mediaType: "image"
        },
        {
          publicId: "products/fl7t8wqkytac7",
          mediaType: "image"
        }
      ],
      displayProps: {
        mode: "classic"
      },
      transition: "slide",
      themeProps: {
        active: "#49c58f"
      },
      aspectRatio: "square",
      zoomProps: {
        trigger: "click"
      },
      carouselLocation: "left",
      carouselStyle: "indicators",
      indicatorProps: {
        shape: "round"
      }
    });
    myWidget.render();
  }
  render() {
    return <div id="my-gallery" className={classes.Gallery}></div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. For making third-party libs control some element inside your React component you need to bind them to [React lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) (for a function component it would be `useEffect`). Supposing you are using Create React App.

First, add the script import in your `public/index.html` file.

```html
<script src="https://product-gallery.cloudinary.com/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

With function components would be something like this:

```js
const FullProduct = () => {
  const cloudnaryGalleryRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!cloudnaryGalleryRef.current) {
      cloudnaryGalleryRef.current = cloudinary.galleryWidget({
        container: '#my-gallery',
        cloudName: 'demo',
        mediaAssets: [
          { tag: 'electric_car_product_gallery_demo' },
          { tag: 'electric_car_product_gallery_demo', mediaType: 'video' },
          { tag: 'electric_car_360_product_gallery_demo', mediaType: 'spin' }
        ]
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return <div id="my-gallery" />;
};
```

And then you can use `cloudnaryGalleryRef.current` to access all the methods the lib gives you.

Comment: thanks, Alyson, I just came up with the same solution but you can not access Cloudinary right away first you have to access Window object, like this Window.cloudinary.galleryWidget

Comment: I was wondering where should I add script import for Next.js framework to access `cloudinary.galleryWidget` . I tried to add it to `_document.js` file but it gives me an error `Cannot read property 'galleryWidget' of undefined`